# How to return a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a button component from material UI. What i wanna do is i click a button and it renders to me a new Button on the screen.
That's what i did

```
const [button, setButton] = useState([]);

function addButton(){

 let newObj = {
      button: <Button variant="contained"> A Button</Button>,
    };

 setButton([...button, newObj])
```

}

And then in the main function return i did

```
{button.length !== 0 ? (
        button.map((item) => {
          <div>{item.button}</div>;
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Hello</div>
      )}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason to store the UI component into the state? Creating a new button on clicking an existing button may be accomplished without needing to hold the component in state.

Comment: But how could i click one button and render as many buttons as i clicked?

Comment: Don't store react elements in state. It's an anti-pattern. Instead store data in state (like an array) and then conditionally or dynamically render elements based on that data

Comment: Actually, what i wanna do is instead of buttons, i want to create new Accordions, like new sections, and then but things inside of it. But i'm not sure how can i keep creating the Accordion component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the component in the map function
like this

```
{button.length !== 0 ? (
        button.map((item) => {
         return (<div>{item.button}</div>);
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Hello</div>
      )}
```

the map function with no 'return' keyword must not have the bracket { }
like this

```
   button.map((item) => (<div>{item.button}</div>))
```

Comment: Ah, c'mon. Virtually identical answer to mine 5 minutes later and this one is accepted. 

Answer (score 4):

When you use a multi-line lambda with braces you need a `return`...

```
button.map((item) => {
      return (<div>{item.button}</div>);
    })
```

Alternatively you can omit the braces...

```
button.map((item) => (<div>{item.button}</div>))
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer tries to address the below problem-statement:

> But how could i click one button and render as many buttons as i
> clicked?

The below snippet provides a demo of how a new button may be rendered when user clicks an existing button. This expands on the below comment

> Creating a new button on clicking an existing button may be
> accomplished without needing to hold the component in state.

Please note:

- It does not store the button elements into the state
- instead, it merely stores the attributes (like the button-label /
  text) into the state

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const MyButton = ({
  btnLabel, btnName, handleClick, isDisabled, ...props
}) => (
  <button
    class="myBtn"
    onClick={handleClick}
    name={btnName}
    disabled={isDisabled}
  >
    {btnLabel}
  </button>
);

const MagicButtons = () => {
  const [btnText, setBtnText] = useState("");
  const [disableBtns, setDisableBtns] = useState(false);
  const [myButtons, setMyButtons] = useState(["A Button"]);
  const handleClick = () => setDisableBtns(true);
  return (
    <div>
      {
        disableBtns && (
          <div class="myInput">
            <input
              value={btnText}
              onChange={e => setBtnText(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setMyButtons(prev => ([...prev, btnText]));
                setBtnText("");
                setDisableBtns(false);
              }}
            >
              Add New Button
            </button>
          </div>
        )
      }
      {
        myButtons.map((txt, idx) => (
          <MyButton
            handleClick={handleClick}
            btnName={idx}
            isDisabled={disableBtns ? "disabled" : ""}
            btnLabel={txt}
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <MagicButtons />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.myBtn { margin: 15px; }
.myInput > input { margin: 15px; }
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```